# Access - recordset search to return a fieldcount with 2 different criteria

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset

I’m looking to display some key data on the home page.. things like, open non conformances for 1 day, 7 days more than 7 days… or count of jobs that should have been complete yesterday that are still open Etc. Ect

*With little success*, I’m trying to get a recordset search to return a fieldcount based on 2 different criteria.. and then I was going to merge the two criteria… but I cant get it working

The first query is trying to count the records between a date range *between now and -7 days*

```
vSQL = "SELECT count(*) AS FieldCount FROM tblNonConformance WHERE [Date] =" & "[Date] Between #" & Format(Now(), "mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss") & "# And #" & Format(Now() - 7, "mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"
```

The second query is counting the number of records that are still open *(from a yes/no field in the db)*

```
vSQL = "SELECT count(*) AS FieldCount FROM tblNonConformance WHERE [NCR Clsd?]=" & False
```

The fieldcount in both cases is coming back as empty *(the logic is if I can’t get them working individually I have no hope of nesting them)*

```
Public Sub Tester124()
Dim vSQL As String
Dim rs As Recordset

'Creating a count SQL statement for the Date Range
   vSQL = "SELECT count(*) AS FieldCount FROM tblNonConformance WHERE [Date] =" & "[Date] Between #" & Format(Now(), "mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss") & "# And #" & Format(Now() - 7, "mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"
'Create a count SQL statement for the closed status
   'vSQL = "SELECT count(*) AS FieldCount FROM tblNonConformance WHERE [NCR Clsd?]=" & False
   
'Set the recordset to variable rs and have it return the query
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(vSQL)

'Displaying the results.. i will do more with this when i have a usable result
    With rs
      MsgBox (FieldCount)
      End With
End Sub
```

Any suggestions while the fieldcount comes back as empty?

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert the date to a date constant.  I'm not sure why the second wouldn't work, but you can combine the two as:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF([Date] < NOW() AND [Date] >= DATEADD("d", -7, NOW()), 1, 0)) as cnt1,
       SUM(IIF([NCR Clsd?], 0, 1)) as cnt2
FROM tblNonConformance;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon.. Thanks for taking the time to help me out,  I still cant get it to work. If I replace the original code vSQL = Select count with the suggested code it goes red and gives a compile error: saying expected case

Comment: Edited. Try again.

Comment: @sambob_628 . . . That seems like a curious message, given that MS Access doesn't support `case`.  I fixed a couple of typos in the answer.

Comment: As HansUp said i have loaded the select statement into the Vsql Variable and that has fixed the case error  however I'm still struggling, I'm getting a compile error expected ) and its highlighting the "d" just after DATEADD... I've checked the property and everything makes sense to me... vSQL = ("SELECT SUM(IIF([Date] < NOW() AND [Date] >= DATEADD("d", -7, NOW()), 1, 0)) as cnt1 FROM tblNonConformance;")

Comment: @sambob_628 . . . All of your errors suggest that you are not using MS Access.

Comment: Ha, I wish it was as simple as using the wrong software. Unfortunately that's not the case, its a real problem I cant seem to solve. I've extracted a copy of the table and home page form into a new blank db and the problem is still there... a copy can be downloaded from file dropper...    http://www.filedropper.com/databasetesting    any suggestion's welcome, I ve been stuck on this for 4 days its really bugging me now